# Barbell exercises for serratus anterior muscle

Tags: barbell

By benchpressing a lot, I improved my chest, but it seems so the side view is still a sticking point due to a weakly developed serratus anterior muscle.

> [image]

I'm going to start overhead pressing but any other exercise recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serratus anterior can't really be worked directly but it is used indirectly through all anterior/front delt exercises and a few select chest exercises such as most plank variations and shoulder raises.

Answer (score 0):

Include scapular push-ups, dumbbell pullovers, and overhead presses.